# Auto-import in import block in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I used Eclipse before and now I am trying to use IntelliJ IDEA (version 13). In Eclipse if I use some new class that in other package, Eclipse adds its import into import block:

```
import a.b.Aclass;

class MainClass {
    Aclass aClass;
}
```

But IntelliJ IDEA adds new class like this:

```
class MainClass {
    a.b.Aclass aClass;
}
```

Can I configure IntelliJ IDEA to import new classes as Eclipse? And how? I viewed settings and can not find this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Settings - Code Style - Java - Imports and there uncheck 'Use fully qualified class names'.

Comment: That option is off by default on a new install. Odd it was checked.